# doesn't return windows

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

I need to add a view to window on iPhone, so i tried to do this: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`, but it seams that the array contains only one window.

Can anyone tell me what i'm not doing write/what i need  to do?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15623745/308315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. Actually conditions where not set correct, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` returned only one window. Still, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` throw an exception.

It was because When `MPVideoPlayerController` starts playing, it starts creating a new window, but, probably does not finish this job immediately. It is created ALMOST immediately, but not immediately.

Answer (score 3):

try

> ```
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
> ```

if you want to find your app's window.

Comment: If [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] retuns nothing, then [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] will throw an exception

Comment: @Morion, in a UITableViewController, after MPMoviePlayerController has started playing. Apple's example works well.

Answer (score 2):

Your AppDelegate class will hold the window (as a property). You only get one window per application. In most cases you should only add views directly to the window from the AppDelegate -- for normal subview management, use viewControllers.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController seams to start into a different window, but I need it to add an overlay on the MoviePlayer window.

Comment: Ah, I see. I found this post about it, which claims to be able to do it on 3.0: http://amromousa.com/2009/03/22/overlay-uiview-on-mpmovieplayercontroller/ but, the usual warning -- Apple might get mad.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
UIView *controllersView = [myViewController view];

[window addSubview:controllersView];
```

Comment: It is on the video window. So i don't have access to view.

Comment: And where did that variable "window" come from?