# UIApplication sharedApplication - keyWindow is nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I want to convert a CGPoint from my UIView to UIWindow coordinates and have realized that  UIApplication keyWindow is always nil; why is this?

I have tried the `convertPoint:toView:` method from UIView.

Please see this sample code I tried in the view controller in a template of Xcode (View application):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *test =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,250,250)];
    [test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:test];

    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    CGPoint np;

    np = [test convertPoint:p toView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    NSLog(@"p:%@ np:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p), NSStringFromCGPoint(np));

    AppDelegate *appDel =  (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    np = [test convertPoint:p toView:[appDel window]];
    NSLog(@"p:%@ np:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p), NSStringFromCGPoint(np));

    np = [test convertPoint:p toView:nil];
    NSLog(@"p:%@ np:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p), NSStringFromCGPoint(np));

    [test release];

    if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow])
        NSLog(@"window was nil");
}
```

and I get:

```
p:{100, 100} np:{100, 100}
p:{100, 100} np:{140, 160}
p:{100, 100} np:{100, 100}
window was nil
```

I can convert it but only when I access the window through the app delegate. And not UIApplication. According to the documentation, keyWindow should work here, but is nil.
Why is this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This code was executed before `[window makeKeyAndVisible];` which is inside the app delegate.
So, no wonder why `keyWindow` was `nil` yet.

Answer (score 39):

Easiest way is to get the window from the app delegate instead:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
// Do something with the window now
```

Comment: Will this still work if your app has multiple windows? Like, what about in a document-based app?

Comment: You mean [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow

Comment: @Laszlo That's not the same thing. One gets its window from the app delegate, one from whichever window might be on top at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

I noticed that after having started the Guided Access, the keyWindow property on [UIApplication sharedApplication] appears to be nil.

It happened to me only on iOS7 when starting the Guided Access Mode for the *first* time after having enabled it in Settings > General > Guided Access, so the starting GAM view is actually displayed and not by-passed.

Since this Apple API seems buggy, I solved using the following code to retrieve the window I'm looking for.

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
if ([windows count]) {
    return windows[0];
}
return nil;
```

Instead of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

maybe you could also try using

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

as [iWasRobbed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308315/iwasrobbed) pointed out but it wasn't working for me as the `rootViewController` property isn't reachable this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first get the `UINavigationController` handle, and then the topViewController

```
let navController = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let yourMainViewController = navController.topViewController as! ItemsViewController
```

or

```
let yourMainViewController = navController.viewControllers.first as! ItemsViewController
```