# Why MBProgressHUD not show, when an alert show before HUD show?

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I use this code to init MBProgressHUD

```
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]  
    _hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithWindow:window];
    _hud.dimBackground = bDim;
    _hud.labelText = message;
    [window addSubview:_hud];
    [_hud show:YES];
```

but sometimes _hud not show in window ?
Anyone let me know where im lack here??
Thanks!

Comment: may be your key window is nil at that moment. add a log and test.

Comment: I believe `UIAlertView` has its own window which shows in front of the key window, so your HUD is probably blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359501/uiapplication-sharedapplication-keywindow-is-nil)!
This works for me .Just use this window.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

Or
 you can use

```
self.navigationController.view
```

to add you HUD.